# Removing consecutive symbols/characters found after a word for multiple tokens

Tags: python, string, replace

A weird icon is repeated after different words/tokens. An example is shown below:

[image: symbol]

Thus far, I have removed it using replace command, however this can become tedious if it is done individually for each word.

The symbol shown in the image is represented as `\x9d.` The current python code is shown below:

```
import re
 text = ['unstable',
 'people\x9d.',
 'pattern',
 'real',
 'thought',
 'fearful',
 'represent',
 'contrarians\x9d',
 'greedy',
 'interesting',
 'behaviour',
 'opposite']
  text = [k.replace('basket\x9d.', 'basket') for k in text]
  text = [k.replace('people\x9d.', 'people') for k in text]
  text = [k.replace('portfolios.\x9d', 'portfolios') for k in text]
```

I have tried to detect patterns using re.sub but have not been successfully in achieving this.

```
text = [re.sub('\x9d', '', str(k)) for k in text]
```

This code will remove the word completely.

Comment: So, what about [`[k.replace('\x9d.', '') for k in text]`](https://ideone.com/noU1Md)? Or do you want to keep it after `contrarians`? Do you have a list of words to remove the special symbol after or some filter list?

Comment: it works text =['unstable',
 'people\x9d.',
 'pattern',
 'real',
 'thought',
 'fearful',
 'represent',
 'contrarians\x9d.',
 'greedy',
 'interesting',
 'behaviour',
 'opposite']   text = [k.replace('\x9d.', '') for k in text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you need to remove a sequence of two chars, `\x9d` and `.`.

You can use a simple `str.replace` in a list comprehension:

```py
text = [k.replace('\x9d.', '') for k in text]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/noU1Md):

```py
import re
text = ['unstable','people\x9d.','pattern','real','thought','fearful','represent','contrarians\x9d','greedy','interesting','behaviour','opposite']
text = [k.replace('\x9d.', '') for k in text]
print(text)
# => ['unstable', 'people', 'pattern', 'real', 'thought', 'fearful', 'represent', 'contrarians\x9d', 'greedy', 'interesting', 'behaviour', 'opposite']
```